# What mechanism allows linux less command to read an encrypted gpg file

Tags: linux, encryption, gnupg

After encrypting a file using symmetric encryption, I decided to confirm that the output was encrypted by typing:

```
gpg -c --force-mdc --s2k-mode 3 --s2k-count 65011712 --output doc.gpg doc.txt

less doc.gpg
```

To my astonishment, the less command automatically decrypted the contents of doc.gpg and displayed them to me, rather than displaying the raw encrypted contents of the file. This happens only with the "less" command and not with the "cat" command. If "less doc.gpg" is done on a different machine, a command line popup dialog will appear asking for the password.

Could anyone please explain what mechanism is causing gpg to integrate automatically with the "less" command, and what other commands this automatic integration will occur with? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with this:

```
$ man less
```

Read a bit, and find:

> **INPUT PREPROCESSOR**
>
> You  may  define an "input preprocessor" for less.  Before less opens a
>   file, it first gives your input preprocessor a chance to modify the way
>   the  contents of the file are displayed...
>
> ...To  set  up  an input  preprocessor, set the LESSOPEN environment variable
>   to a command line which will invoke your  input  preprocessor.   This  command
>   line should  include  one  occurrence  of  the  string  "%s",  which will be
>   replaced by  the  filename  when  the  input  preprocessor  command  is
>   invoked.

Comment: Thank you, that's fantastic.